# Evaluating $\int_0^1 x^n\ln(1/x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How do I go about evaluating $$\int_0^1 x^n\ln(1/x)dx$$
using the fact that $$\int_0^1 x^ndx = 1/(n+1)$$
It appears the integral of interest converges only for $n>-1$. I tried employing power series formulas such as
$$\ln(1/x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n{\big({1\over x} - 1\big)^{n+1}\over n+1}$$
so that
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^n\ln(1/x)dx &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1x^n (-1)^n{({1\over x}-1)^{n+1}\over n+1}dx \\
&= \int_0^1 x^n dx\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n\over n+1}\bigg({1\over x} - 1\bigg)^{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n\over (n+1)^2}\bigg({1\over x}-1\bigg)^{n+1}
\end{align}
But I checked this series on Wolfram and it isn't correct.

Comment: Good grief. Isn’t $\ln(1/x)=-\ln x$? Then just integrate by parts.

Comment: Your series expansion is not valid for $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways.

$\textbf{Method 1}$: Let $u = x^{n+1}$

$$I = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\int_0^1-\log u\:du = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

$\textbf{Method 2}$: By Feynman's trick we can use your hint

$$I = \int_0^1-\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\left(x^n\right)dx = -\frac{d}{dn}\int_0^1x^n\:dx = - \frac{d}{dn}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$